# Angular and HTML Checkbox

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

I have a variable that is either 1 or 0 called `{{CurrentItem.STATUS}}`

How do I make the checkbox checked/unchecked depending on the value of `{{CurrentItem.STATUS}}`. 1 = Checked & 2 = Unchecked. I would prefer an Angular solution that doesn't need any javascript/typescript.

Something like this would be perfect:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="{{CurrentItem.STATUS}} == 1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two-way data binding with `ngModel`

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="CurrentItem.STATUS">
```

This will work as `0` is considered [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JS

Comment: Thank you! :) Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="CurrentItem.STATUS == 1">
```

Comment: Is `CurrentItem.STATUS` supposed to change when you check/uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: Nope not necessary, just for initializing values :)